# Wordpress TinyMCE - Link Editing Bug

Tags: wordpress, debugging, tinymce

I have an issue when editing links within a Wordpress (self-hosted) post. TinyMCE's link-editor provides the option to set/unset "nofollow" for the given link. The issue I'm having is that when I choose to add "nofollow" to any link in the post, it adds it to ALL the links in the post.

Likewise, whenever I unset "nofollow" for any link, it removes it for all of them. Please see this video for an example of the bug.
https://youtu.be/nqSUBB0JMBk

I don't have any other plugins installed that alter the links, and this is happening directly within the Wordpress backend, so I believe the bug to be in TinyMCE specifically. Any direction that would help me to fix this bug would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The link dialog in your video is actually not the "core" link dialog that TinyMCE comes with - that is a WordPress specific dialog provided by WordPress.  Its certainly possible that someone here could provide you ideas on how to fix this but it may be better to file a bug report with WordPress themselves.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback. I'll certainly contact Wordpress. If anyone else comes along and has ideas to fix the issue, I'm all ears! :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I've discovered that the bug is contained in the EasyRecipe plugin. Wordpress/TinyMCE doesn't add the "nofollow" checkbox to the link-editor -- the EasyRecipe plugin (version 3.5.3239) does.

I've contacted EasyRecipe directly for a solution.